# Linked List Class __str__ function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create this function

```
    >>> str(Link('Hello'))
    'Hello'

    >>> str(Link(1, Link(2)))
    '1 -> 2'

    >>> print(Link(1 / 2, Link(1 // 2)))
    0.5 -> 0

    >>> str(Link(Link(1, Link(2, Link(3))), Link(4, Link(5))))
    '(1 -> 2 -> 3) -> 4 -> 5'

    >>> print(Link(Link(Link(Link('Wow')))))
    (((Wow)))

    >>> print(Link(Link('a'), Link(Link('b'), Link(Link('c')))))
    (a) -> (b) -> (c)
```

Here is my code:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = ''
    while self.rest is not Link.empty:
        result += '{0} -> '.format(self.first)
        self = self.rest
    return result + '{0}'.format(self.first)
```

However, I do not know what to do in order to fulfill the last three doctests.
Help!!!

```
class Link(object):
   empty = ()
   def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
       self.first = first
       self.rest = rest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the rule is supposed to be that if the head of a list is itself a list, you format that list, and put it in parentheses. Something like this:

```
first = '({0})'.format(self.first) if isinstance(self.first, Link) else first
result += '{0} -> '.format(first)
```

Now, it's a bit strange to avoid using recursion on `rest`, but then indirectly use recursion on `first`. (That's what `'{0}'.format(…)` does—if you haven't defined a `__format__` method, it calls your `__str__` method.)

So, assuming this is an assignment, if the assignment tells you to not use recursion, you're going to need to turn that into a loop. If, on the other hand, the assignment doesn't say to avoid recursion, it would be a lot simpler to just recurse on both:

```
first = str(self.first)
if isinstance(self.first, Link):
    first = '({0})'.format(first)
if self.rest is Link.empty:
    return first
return '{0} -> {1}'.format(first, self.rest)
```

---

As a side note: This is a stock Scheme exercise ported badly to Python (which implies that your teacher either doesn't get or doesn't like Python, which isn't a great sign…), but it's missing a piece.

Normally, you're supposed to handle, e.g., `Link(1, 2)` differently from `Link(1, Link(2))`. (In Lisp terms, that's `(1 . 2)` vs. `(1 2)`.) But none of the examples you gave test for that, so it's not clear exactly *what* you're supposed to output for the former. Sp… be prepared to be marked off for not reading your teacher's mind, unless you want to do something like this:

```
first = str(self.first)
if isinstance(self.first, Link):
    first = '({0})'.format(first)
if self.rest is Link.empty:
    return first
rest = str(self.rest)
if isinstance(self.rest, Link):
    return '{0} -> {1}'.format(first, self.rest)
else:
    # surely (1 2 . 3) is not the same list as (1 2 3) but the spec left it out?
    return '{0} .. {1}'.format(first, self.rest)
```